# Count user comments from yesterday

Tags: laravel

I have a  `user->hasMany-> posts->hasMany ->comments` relation.

I want to get all user comments in different posts where the comments left yesterday and count the comments.

What I am doing so far:

```
$user = User::where("id", $id)->with("comments")->where(["comments"=>function ($a){

   return $a->where("created_At", DB::Raw("YESTERDAY(created_at)"))
}])->get();
```

But it returns me all the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be:

```
$posts = Post::where("user_id", $id)->with(["comments"=> function ($query){
          $query->where("comments.created_at", Carbon::yesterday());
})->get();

$countComments = $posts->sum(function($query){
   return $query->comments->count();
});
```

`$countComments` should now give you the number of user comments from yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load user with counted comments from all posts, use `withCount()`:

```
User::withCount(['postsComments' => function($q) {
    return $q->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::yesterday());
}])
->find($id);
```

To make it work, define a new `hasManyThrough` relationship:

```
public function postsComments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Comment::class, Post::class);
}
```

Comment: but that doesnt give me the number of all comments from all user posts, it gives me no of comments foreach post

Comment: @PrStandup did you copy the code as is or modify it? If you didn't modify it, please show the results of `dd($results);`

Comment: of course I modified the code, it gives me the posts with a posts_comments_count

Comment: @PrStandup please show what exactly code do you use now.

Comment: @PrStandup I've updated the answer. I've tested this and it works perfectly with the same relationships that you use. Please do not modify the code, just change relationship name.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
$yesterday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( '-1 days' ) );

$user = User::where("id", $id)->with("comments")->where(["comments"=>function ($a) use ($yesterday) {
   return $a->whereDate('created_at', $yesterday )
}])->get();
```

Comment: yeah but I want the count of all comments on all posts